# Efficent search through list items

Tags: python

I have a list `lst` (with 10K items) and query term `q`, and I want to find if any item in `lst` ends with `q`.

As a reference timer I set to 1, this statement:

```
x = q in lst
```

I tried these:

```
# obvious endswith method
y = [k for k in lst if k.endswith(q)]
# find method
z = [k for k in lst if k.find(q, len(k)-len(q))]
# regex
v = [k for k in lst if re.search(q + '$', k)]
# regex without list comprehension
w = re.search(q + '~', '~'.join(lst) + '~')
```

With these results (timed against `x` timer):

```
x: 1
y: 650
z: 1209
v: 7160
w: 241
```

So I guess I could go with regex and joined list, unless there is better implementation.

*In real world I'm trying to optimize code block that's hit multiple times on execution, and I detected that list comprehension with `.endswith` method is bottleneck.*

Comment: Do you only want to find if any item in `lst` ends with `q`, or do you need a list of the items ending with `q`?

Comment: Just to find if there is such item - true/false

Comment: `'~'.join(lst)` in regex search can be assigned outside the loop, which gives regex search 3x boost, when using this kind of a search in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think regex is the way to go. Even when I assign `joined = '~'.join(lst) + '~'` outside of the loop, `q+'~' in joined` outperforms `re.search(q + '~', joined)` (0.00093 seconds vs 0.0034 seconds).

However, assuming that you won't already have the joined string, a method not requiring it might be faster. A generator might be useful because it only produces values as you need them (so that as soon you find your query at the end of one of your items you can stop, instead of checking the rest of the list).

This was the fastest for me: `any(k for k in lst if k.endswith(q))`

My code:

```
import timeit

setup = '''

import string
import random
import re

lst = []
for i in range(10000):
    lst.append(random.choice(string.letters)+random.choice(string.letters)+random.choice(string.letters)+random.choice(string.letters))

q = 'ab'

'''

print "reference: "
print round(min(timeit.Timer("q in lst", setup=setup).repeat(7,500)),5)
# 0.05435

print "\nreference with joined string: "
print round(min(timeit.Timer("q+'~' in '~'.join(lst) + '~'", setup=setup).repeat(7,500)),5)
# 0.05462

print "\nendswith, with list approach: "
print round(min(timeit.Timer("any([k for k in lst if k.endswith(q)])", setup=setup).repeat(7,500)),5)
# 0.62998

print "\nfind method: "
print round(min(timeit.Timer("[k for k in lst if k.find(q, len(k)-len(q))]", setup=setup).repeat(7,500)),5)
# 1.22274

print "\nregex: "
print round(min(timeit.Timer("[k for k in lst if re.search(q + '$', k)]", setup=setup).repeat(7,500)),5)
# 3.73494

print "\nregex without list comprehension: "
print round(min(timeit.Timer("re.search(q + '~', '~'.join(lst) + '~')", setup=setup).repeat(7,500)),5)
# 0.05435

print "\nendswith, with generator approach: "
print round(min(timeit.Timer("any((k for k in lst if k.endswith(q)))", setup=setup).repeat(7,500)),5)
# 0.02052
```

Comment: Excellent. I somehow forgot obvious `q+'~' in joined` and after I compared the results with the generator in my code, I found it's the best approach. Thanks :)

Comment: `any()` in generator is nice idea, but often there is no hit in my loop so it's not as efficient as `q+'~' in joined`